# Regular expression for int and float both not working fine

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to allow user to only enter integer (33) and float (33.343) in a textbox.

Below is my Regex Query but it is not working fine. It is allowing the user to enter float values but giving error on int values.but i need to allow user to  enter int also. It is working fine and giving error message when user enter any other type of value.

```
/^[0-9]*[.][0-9]*$/
```

Answer (score 3):

Make dot and the part after it optional:

```
"^\d+(?:\.\d+|)$"
```

Also prefer `\d` over `[0-9]`, don't use `*` since then you allow the possibility of no number either side of the `.`

This will accept:

```
1
1.23
```

but not:

```
.1
23.
```

It's up to you if you want that behaviour.

Comment: I didn't down-vote you but you create an unnecessary group.  I think you mean: "^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$"

Comment: Would mot match `.123` or `123.` - both valid numbers/formats

Comment: Not in my compiler: `warning C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data`

Comment: @Ωmega, I think it really depends on the situation whether those should be considered valid.

Comment: @Ωmega, fair enough, but the real question is whether Asp_Newbie wants those to be considered valid user input.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Comment: @Florent - To whom did you address your above comment?

Comment: @dan1111 - This solution would not match valid numbers such as `.123` or `123.`

Comment: @Ωmega I think that depends on the situation.

Comment: I know that it will work with `parseInt` but I though the OP wanted valid integers and floats in a _visual_ way.

Answer (score 2):

Use regex pattern

```
^(?=.*\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?$
```

This will match for example:

```
1234
123.
1.23
12.3
0.12
.123
```

Comment: +1 for use of \d, but I would suggest: "^\d*\.?\d+$" to prevent a dot with no value, e.g "33.", or to allow positive/negative values: "[+\-]?^\d*\.?\d+$"

Comment: @Blazes - But `33.` is a valid number/format, so...? Better keep that allowed :)

Comment: You should use `+` instead of `*`

Comment: looked at some BNF definitions, and fair-enough - "33." is a valid integer.

Comment: My C++ compiler doesn't regard `1.` as an int, it throws a warning saying it had to convert a `double` to an `int` and lost precision.  So it really depends what you regard as valid.

Comment: @Benj - This quesiton is tagged with `javascript`

Comment: Yes but javascript is the language used to perform the match, it's not clear what use the data will be put to.  Form entry data can go anywhere.

Comment: @Ωmega Sure, we've already established that this is a valid number in javascript.  The point is we don't know where the data is going.

Comment: @Ωmega You already saw the compiler warning.  Let's just leave it to the OP shall we and they can decide which behaviour they want.